# iPhone App requires GPS, how to prevent to install on iPad touch, iPad w/o GPS

Tags: iphone, gps

I'm about to publish a App that requires GPS.

How can I prevent users to install it on a iPod-Touch and iPad w/o GPS?

//Stefan

Comment: This isn't necessarily a good requirement for your app to have. Just because users have a device that can use GPS doesn't mean its on, or that they are happy to "share their location" with your app. Plus there are other ways for the device to find the users location, ie through WIFI or 3G.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s a `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in the `Info.plist` file for this. It can be either a dictionary or an array. In your case you can make it an array and add a single string item that contains the `gps` string. More information in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW7) (or [Google for the key name](http://www.google.com/search?q=UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities)). You should read the App Programming Guide anyway, it contains a lot of important information.